# Checking for new data on server

Tags: json, performance, nsurlconnection

I have an application that downloads data via NSURLConnection in the form of a JSON object; it then displays the data to the user. As new data may be created on the server at any point, what is the best way to 'realise' this and download this data?

At the moment I am planning on having the application download all the data every 30-40 seconds, and then check the data downloaded against the current data: if it is the same do nothing; if it is different, procede with the alterations. However, this seems a bit unnecessary, especially as the data may not change for a while. Is there a more efficient way of updating the application data when new server data is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ETag if the server supports it.

[Wikipedia ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)
"If the resource content at that URL ever changes, a new and different ETag is assigned."

Answer (score 1):

You could send a HTTP HEAD request to the server with the "If-Modified-Since" header set to the time you recieved the last version. If the server handles this correctly, it should return 304 (Not Modified) while the file is unchanged; so as soon as it doesn't return that, you GET the file and procede as usual.
See [HTTP/1.1: Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14)

Comment: I can't seem to access the link: "Request forbidden by administrative rules."

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo (quotes at the end of the link due to a missing space). It should work now :) Search for "14.25 If-Modified-Since"